# Is the behaviour of Python's list += iterable documented anywhere?

Tags: python, operators, containers

It would appear that in Python, `list += x` works for any iterable `x`:

```
In [6]: l = []

In [7]: l += [1]

In [8]: l += (2, 3)

In [9]: l += xrange(5)

In [10]: l
Out[10]: [1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Is this behaviour documented anywhere?

To contrast this with `list + x`, the latter only works if `x` is also a `list`. This is spelled out in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange).

Comment: I'll look for some documentation to back it up, but I believe in the case of a list the `+=` operator mimics `extend`. I'll see if I can find something to confirm this.

Comment: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0203/

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: I actually looked at the PEP before posting the question, but didn't find anything specifically about `+=` and lists. Is there some part I am overlooking?

Comment: @NPE may be this http://p.boxnet.eu/16970/, also from the same PEP: `The `i' in `__iadd__' stands for `in-place`, and if you call the module `dis` on `+=` then you'll see that it is in-place add only.

Comment: Yeah, I can't remember where it says, but `+=` gets proxied to `.extend()` which in turn is `list[len(list):] = other`...

Comment: The closest I have found is a remark in the [`__iadd__` documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iadd__) that " These methods should attempt to do the operation in-place (modifying self) [...]".

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From [Guido van Rossum](https://plus.google.com/118069851186709403898/posts/YoNDMKjTuJh):

> It works the same way as `.extend()` except that it also returns `self`. I
>   can't find docs explaining this. :-(

Here is the relevant source code taken from [`listobject.c`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2d2d4807a3ed/Objects/listobject.c#l892):

```
list_inplace_concat(PyListObject *self, PyObject *other)
{
     PyObject *result;

     result = listextend(self, other);
     if (result == NULL)
         return result;
     Py_DECREF(result);
     Py_INCREF(self);
     return (PyObject *)self;
}
```

I've raised a bug report to have the documentation fixed: http://bugs.python.org/issue16701

Comment: Ha, +1 - you were two sections ahead of me :)

Comment: The question asks for *documentation* of this behavior. Source code isn't documentation, and the PEP does not (as far as I can tell from skimming and grepping) define the semantics of `+=` for lists, only the fallback behavior (which lists override). Am I missing something or are you not actually answering the question? -1 for now.

Comment: @delnan What if this thing is actually missing from the docs, docs can have bugs too.

Comment: "It's not documented" is a valid answer I guess ;-) But that's not what this answer says.

Comment: @delnan That PEP did helped me in finding the function,it says  that sequences have their own methods for augmented assignments. For eg. `binaryfunc sq_inplace_concat;`

Comment: I've taken the liberty to reorganize the answer a bit. Hope you're OK with this.

Comment: Note though that Guido talking on a mailing list isn't documentation.

Comment: Unfortunately the link to Guido's comment is broken. I haven't been able to find a current link to replace it with.

Comment: @ForeverWintr Works for me but requires log in.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary. Oh, my mistake. I guess my google account doesn't have access to that post for some reason.

Answer (score 5):

It is [now documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) in Python 3.4+ and Python 2.7:

> **4.6.3. Mutable Sequence Types**
>
> The operations in the following table are defined on mutable sequence types. The `collections.abc.MutableSequence` ABC is provided to make it easier to correctly implement these operations on custom sequence types.
>
> *[Below]* `s` is an instance of a mutable sequence type, `t` is any iterable object and `x` is an arbitrary object that meets any type and value restrictions imposed by `s` (for example, `bytearray` only accepts integers that meet the value restriction `0 <= x <= 255`).
>
> ---
>
> **`s.extend(t)` or `s += t`**
>
> extends `s` with the contents of `t`  (for the most part the same as `s[len(s):len(s)] = t`)

So it is now documented that for any mutable sequence type `s`, `s += t` is synonymous with `s.extend(t)`.

Answer (score 4):

No ([Guido confirms](https://plus.google.com/118069851186709403898/posts/YoNDMKjTuJh); thanks to Ashwini Chaudhary). The behaviour of `+=` for sequences in general is underspecified. I conclude that it is not required by the specification that `x + y` where `x` is a list, and `y` some other iterable be an error (so other implementations could choose to allow it), and that other implementations could restrict `+=` to require homogenous operands.

However, the reasons not to do this are obvious: python in general tries to do the right thing with operands, rather than requiring rigid type equality. The real mystery is why heterogenous addition is not allowed with lists.

Update: I've never really thought about the nonhomogenous addition problem, largely because `itertools.chain` is pretty much a complete solution to the problem.

Comments from those more familiar with Python's internals are welcome to explain why addition is required to be homogenous. (Question here: [Why must Python list addition be homogenous?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13905008/why-must-python-list-addition-be-homogenous))

Comment: @NPE I'm very surprised to realise that this behaviour is not documented. I've never actually questioned the nonheterogenous `+`, largely because where I want to concatenate a list, and other iterables, I use `itertools.chain` to avoid the need for copying, except in relation to strings.

Comment: I think the last paragraph deserves a separate SO question. I too have been wondering about this for a long time.

Answer (score -1):

For the performance freaks out there, yes, `+=` is a tiny bit faster than `extend`:

```
>>> from timeit import repeat
>>> min(repeat('a.extend((1,2,3,4,5,6,7))', 'a=[]'))
0.23489440699995612
>>> min(repeat('e((1,2,3,4,5,6,7))', 'a=[]; e = a.extend'))
0.2214308570000867
>>> min(repeat('a+=(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)', 'a=[]'))
0.21909333300027356
```

And here is how it compares to `append`:

```
>>> min(repeat('a.append(1)', 'a=[]'))
0.062107428999297554
>>> min(repeat('p(1)', 'a=[]; p = a.append'))
0.04968810399986978
>>> min(repeat('a+=(1,)', 'a=[]'))
0.0501599309991434
```

(Testing on Python 3.7 64-bit, Windows)