# Python global list modification inside and outside of functions

Tags: python

2I'm relatively new to Python (using 3.3.3) and have a list related question. When modifying a global list variable inside a function (please, no lectures on the evils of global variables), you typically do not need to declare the list with the global keyword inside the function - provided you stick to list methods. In particular, you may not use augmented addition without first using the global keyword. What surprises me is that using augmented addition outside the function clearly isn't modifying the list variable (only the list contents), and so I would expect to be allowed to use it inside a function without using the global keyword. Here are two examples that I can't reconcile:

```
list_1 = []

def my_func():
    list_1.append(0)
    #list_1 += [0]

my_func()
print('list_1 =', list_1)
```

This prints `list_1 = [0]`, as expected, while the commented out augmented addition operation generates a complaint about using a local variable before assignment.

Here's an example that I can't reconcile with the previous one:

```
list_1 = [0]
list_2 = list_1
list_1 += [1]
print('list_2 =', list_2)
```

This prints `list_2 = [0, 1]`, which suggests to me that `list_1 += [1]` did not modify the list_1 variable. I'm aware that `list_1 = list[1] + [1]` qualifies as modifying list_1, but augmented addition doesn't seem to. Why does augmented addition, inside a function, require use of the global keyword? Thanks for any help understanding this.

Comment: Did you try printing out `list_1` to check your hypothesis that `list_1 += [1]` didn't modify `list_1`?

Comment: You say "This prints `list_2 = [0, 1]`, which suggests to me that `list_1 += [1]` did not modify the `list_1` variable."  Why does that suggest that to you?

Comment: @BrenBarn I believe Jon means that `list_1 += [1]` did not cause `list_1` to point to a different list, whereas `list_1 = list_1 + [1]` creates a new list and has `list_1` point to that new list.

Comment: @ Rob Watts Yes, that's exactly what I mean.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UnboundLocalError in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9264763/unboundlocalerror-in-python)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is when a function body is parsed all the variables used in either normal assignments or augmented assigments are considered as local variables, so when the function gets called Python will not look for those variables in global scope hence it will raise an error. Hence you need to specify those variables as `global` to tell Python to look for them in global scope.

Another alternative is to use `list.extend()` instead of `+=`.

Related:

- [Why am I getting an `UnboundLocalError` when the variable has a value?](https://docs.python.org/3.3/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value)
- [Is the behaviour of Python's list `+=` iterable documented anywhere?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13904493/is-the-behaviour-of-pythons-list-iterable-documented-anywhere)

Comment: I would say it is a matter of readability and consistency. if `list_1` was an int, `+=` would reassign, and therefore it would make sense that `global` must be used. It makes sense that `+=` will have the same effect on globalness for all types

Comment: FYI, OP asked about Python 3.x, but your first link is the Python 2.x docs.

Comment: @njzk2 If I got your point correctly then for immutable types it doesn't matter whether you use `+=` or plain `=`, because in any way it going to update only a single variable and all the other references are going to be unaffected. So, `+=` is going to have a different effect based on the object's type.

Comment: @RobWatts Updated the link, except the `nonlocal` part they're essentially the same.

Comment: @Aशwiniचhaudhary: yes. If you look at `a = 3; id(a); a += 1; id(a)` vs  `lst = []; id(lst); lst += [0]; id(lst)`, you'll see that `+=` reassigns the immutable type (has to, obviously) but does not reassign the list.

Comment: (all of which because `__iadd__` falls back on `__add__` for classes where `__iadd__` is not defined)

Comment: @Aशwini चhaudhary That sounds reasonable. So, identifying the object on which a method is called is handled differently? Meaning, when `list_1.append(0)` is parsed in `my_func()`, `list_1` is **not** considered to be a local variable? What is the reason for this difference? (The extend() method looks helpful!)

Comment: @Jon Yes, Other things like fetching the value of an object follow the LEGB rule. One reason could be optimization, value lookup for locals is very fast.

Comment: @Jon I'd suggest you to read [Understanding UnboundLocalError in Python](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/05/15/understanding-unboundlocalerror-in-python/) and [Python internals: Symbol tables, part 1](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2010/09/18/python-internals-symbol-tables-part-1/).

Comment: @Aशwini चhaudhary When I read your UnboundLocalError link above, I wasn't able to recognize an explanation, but I _was_ able to understand the UnboundLocalError link you just posted. My simple take-away is that since `list_1.append(0)` involves only name resolution, rather than assignment or binding, `list_1` is resolved by the nearest enclosing scope. A interesting distinction, and one which also explains why I can use local variables in functions, provided that I don't try to modify them. Thank you!

Comment: I just noticed a typo in my last response - "...why I can use local variables..." should be "...why I can use global variables...".