# Python: Difference between list.extend and list.__iadd__

Tags: python

I thought `list.extend` and "+=" on list basically do the same thing - extends the list without creating new list.

I expect following code to print `[42, 43, 44, 45, 46]` but I'm getting `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment`

Why I'm getting this error? Where is the difference?

```
def f():
    x.extend([43, 44])
def g():
    x += ([45, 46])
x = [42]
f()
g()
print x
```

I tried this in python2.7.3 and python3.4.0.

Comment: @200OK: no, not really. This is about why Python thinks `x` is global in `f`, and a local in `g`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters How about this one: [Python global list modification inside and outside of functions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23436385/846892)

Comment: @200OK: found a more canonical version.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`+=` gives an object the **opportunity** to alter the object in-place. But this depends on the type of `x`, it is not a given that the object is altered in place.

As such, `+=` *still needs to re-assign* to `x`; either `x.__iadd__()` returns `x`, or a new object is returned; `x += something` is really translated to:

```
x = x.__iadd__(something)
```

Because `+=` includes an assignment, `x` is marked as a local in `g()`.

`x.extend()` on the other hand, is not an assignment. The programmer has decided that `x` is always an object with an `.extend()` method and uses it directly. Python sees no assignment and `x` is marked as a global.

Comment: I agree. x.__iadd__ is returning a list, source here: http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/db842f730432/Objects/listobject.c#l914