# Why does augmented assignment behave differently when adding a string to a list

Tags: python, string, list, augmented-assignment

I am in a very interesting situation and I am so surprised.
actually I thought both `i += 1 and i = i + 1` are same. but it'is not same in here;

```
a = [1,2]
a += "ali"
```

and `output is [1,2,"a","l","i"]`

but if I write like that;

```
a = [1,2]
a = a + "ali"
```

it doesn't work.

I am really confused about this.
are they different?

Comment: Well... `i += 1` and `i = i + 1` is not the same. The former modifies existing object `i` whereas the latter creates a new object. Try also `a=[]; b=a; a+=[1]` - it modifies both `a` and `b`, whereas `a = a + [1]` modifies only `a`.

Comment: a=a+"ali" is an error because you can not concatenate list with a string.

Comment: @zvone It's really interesting. probably for you it's normal. but in my university, teacher said they are same. and I watched many videos about programming. and all of them said they are same. I am wondering one thing about this, i += 1 situation can be use instead of other in every position? or not? because i+=1 can creates a new object too.

Comment: @njx They are two separate operations which may or may not do the same thing, depending on the object (`i`). For built-in immutable objects, like `int` and `str`, they will probably do the same, because there is no way to modify the object. For mutable objects I would expect that they are different. That still does not explain why one accepts strings whereas the other does not, but I cannot give you a better answer for that part. To me it actually makes sense, but it could have been implemented differently.

Comment: @zvone - not quite. `__iadd__` and `__add__` both return objects. `list.__iadd__` returns itself while `int.__iadd__` returns a new object. So, `x = 1;x += 1` creates a new object. The objects themselves decide what they should do.

Comment: @tdelaney: Still not quite right. `int.__iadd__` doesn't exist at all, so `+=` falls back to `int.__add__`, which creates a new object. `list.__iadd__` exists, and returns the original, modified list.

Answer (score 4):

## Short answer

The `+` operator concatenates lists while the `+=` operator extends a list with an iterable.

## Long answer

The `+` operator concatenate lists to return a *new* list...

```
l1 = l2 = []
l1 = l1 + [1]

l1 # [1]
l2 # []
```

... while the `+=` operator extends a list, by mutating it.

```
l1 = l2 = []
l1 += [1]

l1 # [1]
l2 # [1]
```

What allows different behaviours is that `+` calls the `__add__` method while `+=` calls the `__iadd__` method.

In your example, you provided a string to the `__iadd__` method, which is equivalent to doing `l.extend('ali')`. In particular, you can extend a list with any iterable, but concatenation arguments must both be lists.

Although, there is a [slight difference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23564988/5079316) between `list.__iadd__` and `list.extend`. The former returns the mutated list, while the later does not.

Answer (score 0):

In python, since you can't declare static types, this behavior doesn't show up, but if you look at C++, if you declare `int a = 4` as an integer and then do `a += 5.4`, `a` will become `9`, whereas `a = a + 5.4` will break.

The reason for this is that `a += b` and `a = a + b` aren't the same. In python terms, `a += b` is just `a.__iadd__(b)` and `a = a + b` is `a = a.__add__(b)`, or if that doesn't exist, `a = b.__radd__(a)`. You can't add lists and strings together using `+` so the second code doesn't work, but `+=` works because it automatically casts certain types to each other, namely converting iterables to each other. You cannot do `a = []; a += ""` but you can do it vice-versa because you can convert the string to a list unambiguously using `list("...")`.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> a = [1,2]
>>> a = a + "ali"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
```

For list data type use the `.append` method:

```
>>> a = [1,2]
>>> a.append("ali")
>>> a
[1, 2, 'ali']
```

The String in Python is defined as a series of characters in a row. So, these "characters" are added to the "list" type as the characters, not as "String". When you want use the `+=` adding operator for the list type, you must specify the type of the added variable or value using square brackets:

```
>>> a = [1,2]
>>> a += ["ali"]
>>> a
[1, 2, 'ali']

>>> a += ["foo",3,"bar"]
>>> a
[1, 2, 'ali', 'foo', 3, 'bar']
```